# Supposing $h$ has a pole, order m, at $z_0$, show the existence of a neighbourhood of $z_0$ and a new complex differentiable function $g$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

Suppose that $h$ has a pole of order $m\in\mathbb{N}$ at the point $z_0$. Show that there exists a neighbourhood of $z_0$ and a complex differentiable function $g$, so that $g(z_0)=z_0$, where $g'(z_0)\neq0$ and $h(g(z))=(z-z_0)^{-m}$

Here's what I have considered so far, based on a proof in my notes:

If $h$ has a pole of finite order $m$ at $z_0$, then near $z_0$,

$h(z)=\frac {c_m}{(z-z_0)^m}+\frac {c_{m-1}}{(z-z_0)^{m-1}}+...+\frac {c_1}{(z-z_0)}+b_0+b_1(z-z_0)+b_2(z-z_0)^2+...$

$\Rightarrow(z-z_0)^mh(z)=c_m+c_{m-1}(z-z_0)+...+c_1(z-z_0)^{m-1}+b_0(z-z_0)^m+b_1(z-z_0)^{m+1}+...$

$\Rightarrow\frac {d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}} \{(z-z_0)^mh(z)\}=(m-1)!c_1+[m(m-1)...]2b_0(z-z_0)+[(m+1)m...]3b_1(z-z_0)^2+...$

$\Rightarrow c_1=\frac 1{(m-1)^2}\lim_{z\to z_0}[\frac {d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}} \{(z-z_0)^mh(z)\} ]$

By deriving the pole, $c_1$ we show that there exists a punctured disk $ D:=\{ z : 0 < |z − z_0| < R \}$, so meeting the existence of the neighbourhood part of the proof.

However, I am now not too sure about the second part, involving the new function $g$.

Comment: You have $h(z) = \frac{w(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}$ with $w$ holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $z_0$ and $w(z_0) \neq 0$. Look at (a branch of) the $m$-th root of $w$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, you will have to forgive me, but I'm not too sure on how to find a branch of the m-th root of w. I rearranged the equation so as to have w(z)=... and then took the m-th root of both sides, but am not too sure what to do now.

Comment: By shrinking the neighbourhood (call it $U$), we can assume that it's a disk, and $w(z) \neq 0$ on that neighbourhood. You probably know that then there is an $m$-th root of $w$, a function $v\colon U \to \mathbb{C}$ with $v(z)^m = w(z)$ for all $z\in U$. If you don't know that, and that's your problem, ask, or check a book, the existence of $m$-th roots and logarithms of non-vanishing functions on a simply connected domain should be treated in every introduction to complex analysis. Then look at the function $a(z) = \frac{z-z_0}{v(z)}$.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!