# Showing there exists a complex differentiable function $g$ satisfying $g(z_0)=z_0$, with $g'(z_0) \neq 0$ and that $h(g(z))=(z−z_0)^{−m}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-writing

This is a follow up to a previous question: ([Supposing $h$ has a pole, order m, at $z_0$, show the existence of a neighbourhood of $z_0$ and a new complex differentiable function $g$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315564/supposing-h-has-a-pole-order-m-at-z-0-show-the-existence-of-a-neighbourho))

I'm trying to show the second part of the question, namely that there exists a complex differentiable function $g$ which satisfies that $g(z_0)=z_0$, with $g'(z_0) \neq 0$ and that $h(g(z))=(z−z_0)^{−m}$.

Here is what I have done so far, using what was suggested and considering a branch of the $m$-th root of $w(z)$ in the following expression of $h(z)$:

We take $h(z)$ to be,

$$h(z) = \frac{w(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}$$

And then move to consider a branch of the $m$-th root of $w(z)$. Rearranging to obtain $w(z)$ explicitly yields,

$$\Rightarrow w(z)=h(z)(z-z_0)^m$$

Then, we consider a branch of the $m$-th root of our function $w(z)$ by introducing the function $v(z)$ as follows,

$$v(z)^m:=w(z)$$

Equating both expressions of $w(z)$ yields:

$$\Rightarrow v(z)^m=h(z)(z-z_0)^m$$

$$\Rightarrow v(z)=h(z)^{\frac 1m}(z-z_0)$$

$$\Rightarrow h(z)^\frac1m=\frac {(z-z_0)}{v(z)}$$

However, I am now not too sure where to go with regards to trying to find this function $g$; I thought that the expression I managed to get might be our $g$ but I keep getting tripped up substituting it into our equation, as well as with the ensuing manipulations. Any tips on where to go with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I see you already got the holomorphic function $v(z)$ such that 
$$h(z) = (\frac{v(z)}{(z-z_0)})^m $$ so 
$$ h(z) = \frac{1}{(\frac{(z-z_0)}{v(z)} + z_0 - z_0)^m} \, .$$
Set $\psi(z) := \frac{(z-z_0)}{v(z)} + z_0 $ and notice that $\psi\, '(z_0) \neq 0$. Then $\psi$ is invertible near $z_0$ i.e. there is $g(z)$ such that near $z_0$ you have $$\psi(g(z)) = z \, .$$ So $$h(g(z)) = \frac{1}{(z - z_0)^m}$$
as you wanted to show.

Comment: Ahh, I see now. Thanks again!

Comment: you are welcome.